# Stripe Java integration payment process using Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, stripe-payments

I am completely new to **Stripe API**. I want to embedded a payment gateway in my java J2EE application using **Spring MVC**. I am using stripe for it.

What I have done so far is I have included `checkout.js` in my checkout page and hit the pay with card button. It then successfully opens a popup which contains the necessary card details.

When clicking on pay button it should go to the stripe and generate a token for me, then redirect to the success page. But I am unable to hold that token in my back-end and do the necessary stuff.

Can you please provide me the sample codes in **Spring MVC** which meet my entire requirements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share some code from your MVC's controller end, so that fix the error of getting token in your backend

Comment: And also provide what do you want to do with that token? charge?

Answer (score 0):

```
this is my controller to redirect to the checkout page
```

@RequestMapping(value="/checkout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String checkout(ModelMap map,HttpServletRequest request){

```
    //String stripePublicKey = "pk_test_vsp3nRQS4PqW0aqP6PG6cdef";
     String stripePublicKey = "pk_test_vsp3nRQS4PqW0aqP6PG6cdef";

    /*  String token = request.getParameter("stripeToken");
        System.out.println("print token @@@@@@@@@@@" + token);
```

*/

```
    map.addAttribute("amount", 50 * 100); // in cents
    map.addAttribute("stripePublicKey", stripePublicKey);
    map.addAttribute("currency", ChargeRequest.Currency.EUR);
    //map.addAttribute("token", ChargeRequest.Currency.EUR);

        return "checkout";
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my service class to charge the card
public class StripeApiImpl implements StripeApi{

```
@Override
public Charge charge(ChargeRequest chargeRequest) throws AuthenticationException, InvalidRequestException, APIConnectionException, CardException, APIException  {


    Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<>();
    chargeParams.put("amount", chargeRequest.getAmount());
    chargeParams.put("currency", chargeRequest.getCurrency());
    chargeParams.put("description", chargeRequest.getDescription());
    chargeParams.put("source", chargeRequest.getStripeToken());

    return Charge.create(chargeParams);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

actually i want to charge a credit card or debit card after check out through stripe .here is my controller to charge a card and so the result page after successful transaction.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/charge", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String charge(ChargeRequest chargeRequest, Model model,HttpServletRequest request)
          throws StripeException {

        Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_9kYpQEbABJQDw7PGSQ2Ji0m7";

        StripeApi stripeApi = new StripeApiImpl();

            chargeRequest.setDescription("Example charge");
            chargeRequest.setCurrency(Currency.EUR);

            chargeRequest.setAmount(5000);
            chargeRequest.setStripeEmail("lipsapatra23@gmail.com");
            Charge charge = stripeApi.charge(chargeRequest);
            model.addAttribute("id", charge.getId());
            model.addAttribute("status", charge.getStatus());
            model.addAttribute("chargeId", charge.getId());
            model.addAttribute("balance_transaction", charge.getBalanceTransaction());
            return "result";
        }
```